# Проблема с layerSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать почти точную копию сайта http://cafedelafonda.com/ все вышло, кроме слайдера, Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).layerSlider is not a function так понимаю из-за этой ошибки, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Лучше приведите конкретный необходимый функционал и Ваш код для него, а не отсутствие кода с присутствием ссылки на некий сайт.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).layerSlider is not a function
```

Данная ошибка возникает по следующим причинам:

1. Скрипт `layerSlider` не загружен
2. Вызов метода `layerSlider` осуществляется до загрузки `js` скрипта библиотеки